# PrestaShop invoices : $order_detail

Tags: prestashop

Can you tell me how to know what exists in the varaible `$order_detail` in invoice.tpl ?

Like `$order_detail.product_name` or `$order_detail.unit_price_tax_excl`.

I try to get the product's short description and the ecotax tax incl., if possible, but I do not know how...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can display the contents of `$order_detail` with `{$order_detail|@print_r}`.

It doesn't contain the short description. You have to override the `PdfInvoiceController` class in `controllers/front/PdfInvoiceController.php` to get it.

Ecotax is available in `{$order_detail.ecotax}`.